# Running a batch file as an admin

Tags: scripting, batch-file, batch

Is it possible to run a batch script as an administer?  We need this to be done without any user interaction, so there can't be any password prompt or UAC popups - is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming batch means some sort of windows then you could use the task scheduler to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Joeware tool - CPAU.exe](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/index.htm)  to accomplish this:

```
cpau.exe -u machinename\administrator -p secret_password -ex "path_to_a_program.exe" -lwop
```

This tool makes easy work of running a program in a privileged context on demand.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming `batch` is refering to the UNIX command, you can issue `batch` commands as root user, too.

Comment: Given that he's referring to Administrator and UAC - he's not.